# TinyMCE advimage Cannot read property 'responseText' of null

Tags: tinymce

All of a sudden one of our sites has developed an issue with TinyMCE, specifically it seems, in relation to the advimage plugin.

When trying to browse the image folder via TinyMCE I get an alert with one of these errors:

In Chrome I get:

> 2can't process ajax,TypeError: Cannot read property 'responseText' of null

In Firefox I get:

> 2can't process ajax,Invalid XML structure

Nothing has changed on this site for a good few months.

We have upgraded to PHP 5.4 very recently, but I don't see why that would be related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be an issue with overly large images in the plugin's upload directory.

On each request, the advimage plugin scans the upload directory (set in your config) and generates thumbnails of any images it finds in there, then sends a list of images off to the client in the form of JSON or XML. If an image is too large to process, (low server memory or something), then the process quits and doesn't return any JSON/XML, hence the seemingly unrelated error message.

Prune any images over 1MB from the uploads directory. You may need to flush the cached thumbs as well. To stop your users/admins from uploading huge images, set an upload limit in the plugins config.

Comment: Good shout!

Cleared large images and that solved it! :)